# Autowiring in optional fields in Spring

Tags: java, spring

I apologize beforehand if this question has already been answered before or if its too easy, but I am relatively new to spring as a DI framework and I have the following problem

```
@Bean
public EnvironmentInfo environmentInfo() {
    return new EnvironmentInfo();
}

@Bean(name = "availabilityZone")
@Autowired
public Optional<String> getAvailabilityZone(EnvironmentInfo envInfo) {
    return envInfo.getAvailabilityZone();  // this returns an Optional<String>
}
```

And then I autowire it in elsewhere like this

```
@Autowired
@Named("availabilityZone")
protected Optional<String> availabilityZone;
```

Now I put a log statement in the getAvailabilityZone and confirmed its called and it evaluates to a Optional with a proper availability zone. However the autowire itself evaluates to Optional.empty

My question is, is there something I am missing from the Autowiring to vend the Optional correctly?

Edit

The problem effectively goes away if I do this

```
@Bean(name = "availabilityZone")
@Autowired
public String getAvailabilityZone(EnvironmentInfo envInfo) {
    return envInfo.getAvailabilityZone().getOrElse("N/A");
}

@Autowired
@Named("availabilityZone")
protected String availabilityZone;
```

Comment: Please give more clear details of your classes structure. What does the method `getAvailabilityZone` of class EnvironmentInfo return? If it does't return an object of Optional.class this code gonna have errors… why @Named annotation… sees quite odd!

Comment: Well envInfo.getAvailabilityZone() has to return optional, otherwise this thing wont even compile. The method on its own (without either annotation) needs to be valid java code. It's irrelevant if its named or not, it does not evaluate either way.

Comment: So it would be just enough to read the documentation of Optional.class!!
The logger probably applies the toString() method…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Autowiring an optional has another meaning, that is why it does not work as you hoped.

I used it in cases where eg. a `JavaMailSender` was not guaranteed to be available but if it was it was available as an `JavaMailSender` injecting worked than as:

```
@Autowired
protected Optional<JavaMailSender> mailSender;
```

The worst answer is that the following works (at least in the most recent spring-boot):

```
@Service
public class TestController {
    @Autowired
    TestController(@Named("availabilityZone") Optional<Optional<String>> availabilityZone) {
        System.out.println(availabilityZone);
    }
}
```

But this makes me cry...

Another option which is a little bit better is:

```
@Bean(name = "availabilityZone")
@Autowired
public String getAvailabilityZone(EnvironmentInfo envInfo) {
    return envInfo.getAvailabilityZone().orElse(null);
}
```

Another solution would be wrapping it in some custom object, but I think returning null for your bean would be good enough.

Comment: Or I can just default it and return a String. That works, but I was curious why it was not evaluating.

Comment: Is that clear now? It is because Optional has a ‘magic’ meaning here.

Comment: No not really. I circumvented the problem for sure, but I still do not understand why it was failing in the first place.

Comment: Because an Optional<ClassA> autowired dependency means that a bean of type ClassA might or might not be available if it’s there it’s injected otherwise empty is injected. That is the reason why it works with the autowired Optional<Optional<String>> and with the nullable bean of type String and the Autowired Optional<String>

Comment: I see, so if is present JavaMailSender then the mailSender is full otherwise not.

Comment: Yes! Any hints how I could make it clearer from the answer above

Comment: I'm crying too with the second snippet! Generally there are many possibilities to attach Lego bricks, but you should ask yourself first, what are you gonna build?!
Take a look at Spring's ObjectProvider¹ Interface which lets you to implement a clean optional injection…

1. https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/ObjectProvider.html

Comment: @RoxcH did you try it / use it. I ended up with `public DemoService(@Named("demo") ObjectProvider<Optional<Optional<String>>> demoInject) {` to get it working which makes me even more sad... With just an optional its empty all along.